# OpenCV: findContours(); - What kernel am I using

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, kernel

Here is a fairly easy question, though I have a hard time answering my own question.

We are a group of five people, that have to write a report and we have to document everything we do etc. In our project, we uses the function 'findContours();' which is a function within the OpenCV library.

We know that the 'findContours();' function runs a Grass-Fire algorithm, though we need to document what kernel we are using, which we don't have a clue about.

The function we runs looks like this:

> findContours( mGreenScale, vecContours, vecHierarchy,         CV_RETR_CCOMP,
>   CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

- **mGreenScale:** Our binary image we run the function upon.
- **vecCountours:** The vector handler that keep tracks on which pixel is a part of the contour.
- **vexHierarchy:** We are not quiet sure what this is, though we think its some sort of array that handles the contour hierarchy, and keeps
  track of what are edge contours and what are non-edge contours.
- The two other inputs to the function is unknown to us, and we think its one of those two that defines the kernel we use.

I hope anybody is capable of identifying what kernel we are using.
Thanks in advance, pleas ask for further information if you feel I missed something out of importance.

**circumstantial explanation:**
We're a small group of not so experienced programmer, who have limited knowledge in C++ and just begun working with OpenCV a month ago. We have a limited time schedule, and a documentation that needs to be done within two weeks. We have already been looking through this exact site: [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#cv.FindContours) though there are still terms we don't understand.
We don't have the necessary time to check through the source code nor the experience to do so.
We think it is a grass-fire algorithm, as we know no other algorithm capable of detecting BLOBS.

Comment: Just a suggestion: instead of repeating that you don't have the necessary time and experience it might be better to try and understand the terms. The link is from the Learning OpenCV book and explains the various terms pretty lucidly. Enough for documentation purposes if you don't want to go any deeper. http://books.google.co.in/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&lpg=PA243&ots=hSF39idGTa&dq=learning%20OpenCV%20find%20contours&pg=PA236#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What each parameter is doing is clearly explained in the OpenCV [documentation](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29)

And you can find the kernel looking into the OpenCV code. It's open-source. But I am not sure if it used any kernel at all. How do you know about the algorithm if you did not check the source?

Comment: **What each parameter is doing is clearly explained in the OpenCV documentation.** 

Define your explanation of 'clearly' as for us, it is confusing.
We don't have the time, nor the experience to search the source code.
We think its a grass-fire algorithm, as we know no other algorithms to check blobs.

Comment: You say **vexHierarchy: We are not quiet sure what this is** The documentation has half a page about it. What exactly you don't understand? **We don't have the time, nor the experience** why are you doing image processing if you don't know what you're doing and have no time to learn? and how we're supposed to help someone that doesn't want to learn, but just copy?

Comment: I don't think you understand our circumstances, and your incapable of answering our question.
We have been working on it for more than a month, and we are soon reaching the deadline.
The way you address this is seems hostile to us, and you don't have the insight view of our circumstances. Take a look at @AruniRC comment to our question. This is the proper way to respond.
We have spend endless hours of learning both c++, OpenCV, Unity not to mention writing a report, and learn the theory behind image processing.

Comment: To answer the question about the contour hiearchy. We simply just don't understand the theory behind a hiearchy when talking about contours. 
What we 'think' it means, is that contours are stored within arrays, which basicly means they are stored in layers. 
By reading that documentation, we still don't understand the theory, but what have contour hiearchy to do with anything with algorithm kernels?

Comment: :) I have spend about two years on my first image processing project, and another year on the second. So I understand you very well! Now, answering your question about hierarchy, the contours can be nested (i.e the contour of an eye is nested in the face contour, and the iris contour stays in the eye contour, in a tree structure). This info is stored in the vexHierarchy, if you extract the contours with the appropriate flag. And all this theory is nicely explained in the book AruniRC recommended you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is such information we are looking for. Hopefully we can use the book AruniRC refered to, we will reply back as soon we have gathered more knowledge then.